# Route "ui-route" not working. TemplateUrl html not visible in ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use ui-router angular js file for routing and its not working when used in a complex scenario. I have posted all my code in Plunker for your view and thanks in advance for your time and help.

```
"use strict";
var app = angular.module( "productManagement", ["ui.router", "common.services", "productResourceMock"] );

  app.config([ "$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
             function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
               // Redirect to home view when route not found
               $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");               
               $stateProvider
                  // Home state routing
                  .state("home", {
                      url: "/",
                      templateUrl: "route-welcome.html"
                    })
                  .state("productList", {
                      url: "/products",
                      templateUrl: "route-productlist.html"
                    })
                  .state("productDetail", {
                      url: "/products/detail/:productId",
                      templateUrl: "route-productdetail.html"
                    })
             }
  ]);
```

[`Plunker link here`](http://plnkr.co/edit/SlW7TAOcX9jjsegAuWLs?p=preview)

Comment: your requests for template pages are being caught by `$httpBackend`.  I'm researching the structure of your code and possible options, but generally `$httpBackend` is only used for Jasmine tests, not code that is supposed to actually render content.

Comment: Awesome..its working. thank you.

Comment: keep in mind, while you have `$httpBackend` in place, you'll either need to mock or pass through **every** network interaction.  If you add another service and it connects to a real server, it will need to be handled in a similar way to these templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requests for template pages are being caught by the `$httpBackend`, which doesn't know about your `.html` files.  It is instead throwing errors like the following:

> Error: Unexpected request: GET route-welcome.html
>
> No more request expected

To fix this, you can add a `passThrough` to your `app.run`:

```
....
$httpBackend.whenGET(productUrl).respond(products);
$httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).passThrough();
....
```